# Spring Boot application, RestTemplate is not picking the proxy configured in Java options

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate, http-proxy, feign

There are some services which are hosted in internet. My application spring boot services are deployed in K8S cluster. The cluster is behind the corporate firewall. When the services which are deployed in the cluster tries to communicate with the services which are hosted in the internet i am OperationTimeOutException. The REST call happens through RestTemplate and in some cases it happens through feign. In either case it is not working.

When i started the micro service i have provided the java options where the proxy configuration is provided.

java -Dhttp.proxyHost= -Dhttp.proxyPort= -Dhttps.proxyHost= -Dhttps.proxyPort= myapp.jar

When i hard code the proxy while creating the RestTemplate as below,

```
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(host,portNr);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,address);
factory.setProxy(proxy);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```

the communication happens and the application is working as expected. Why the RestTemplate is not able to pick the proxy setting provided in Java options?

I dont want to hardcode the proxy in the code.

Comment: You HAVE to implement the proxy configuration for a `RestTemplate` yourself.

Comment: Hi Daria, Thanks. So the Resttemplate will not be able to pick the proxy from Java options? I was searching for a document which states that... if you have one, please share with me.

Comment: No, RestTemplate is unable to pick the properties by itself.

Comment: Hi Daria, Thanks. After adding the _JAVA_OPTIONS-Dhttp.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port> -Dhttps.proxyHost=<host> -Dhttps.proxyPort=<port> in yaml file, It worked without adding to the code.